# HTML5 mobile camera capture doesn't work on server side

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm using HTML5 capture in my application. The html page works fine and directly captures image using camera when i use following tag and store the HTML file in my mobile directly.

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

But when i use the same code in my published version of website the pop up shows multiple options to upload the image file as shown below

[image]

I just want image to be directly uploaded from camera and restrict users to upload file from other locations. Please help.

Comment: I doubt you can control that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: But its working when i tried running file locally. Will you suggest be the alternate way of capturing image directly from mobile camera. But without flash and mobilegap